# LibreOffice can't save to nextcloud shares after upgrade to 19.04

Tags: libreoffice, 19.04, gvfs, webdav, nextcloud

Under 18.04 I could start a new LibreOffice document, click Save, navigate to my nextcloud "Online Account" and save the file.

Under 19.04 I navigate to the share/folder and on hitting Save it gives two errors:

> Error saving the document Foo: Non-existent file.

and then

> Error saving the document Foo: General Error. General input/output error.

The only workaround I've found is to save to the desktop, then cut-and-paste (because drag n drop no longer works either, #upgradeRegret) from there to a Nautilus (Files) window that's showing the nextcloud share where it should live.

Oddly, if I open an existing document on a nexcloud share it opens in LibreOffice no problem and I can save to it no problem, too.

Is there a fix for this?